# Numpy find number of occurrences in a 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a numpy function to count the number of occurrences of a certain value in a 2D numpy array. E.g.

```
np.random.random((3,3))

array([[ 0.68878371,  0.2511641 ,  0.05677177],
       [ 0.97784099,  0.96051717,  0.83723156],
       [ 0.49460617,  0.24623311,  0.86396798]])
```

How do I find the number of times `0.83723156` occurs in this array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count the number of times `x` appears in any array, you can simply sum the boolean array that results from `a == x`:

```
>>> col = numpy.arange(3)
>>> cols = numpy.tile(col, 3)
>>> (cols == 1).sum()
3
```

It should go without saying, but I'll say it anyway: this is not very useful with floating point numbers unless you specify a range, like so:

```
>>> a = numpy.random.random((3, 3))
>>> ((a > 0.5) & (a < 0.75)).sum()
2
```

This general principle works for all sorts of tests. For example, if you want to count the number of floating point values that are integral:

```
>>> a = numpy.random.random((3, 3)) * 10
>>> a
array([[ 7.33955747,  0.89195947,  4.70725211],
       [ 6.63686955,  5.98693505,  4.47567936],
       [ 1.36965745,  5.01869306,  5.89245242]])
>>> a.astype(int)
array([[7, 0, 4],
       [6, 5, 4],
       [1, 5, 5]])
>>> (a == a.astype(int)).sum()
0
>>> a[1, 1] = 8
>>> (a == a.astype(int)).sum()
1
```

You can also use [`np.isclose()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) as described by [Imanol Luengo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38228464/577088), depending on what your goal is. But often, it's more useful to know whether values are in a *range* than to know whether they are arbitrarily close to some arbitrary value.

The problem with `isclose` is that its default tolerance values (`rtol` and `atol`) are arbitrary, and the results it generates are not always obvious or easy to predict. To deal with complex floating point arithmetic, it does [even more](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/numeric.py#L2454-L2459) floating point arithmetic! A simple range is much easier to reason about precisely. (This is an expression of a more general principle: [first, do the simplest thing that could possibly work](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoTheSimplestThingThatCouldPossiblyWork).)

Still, `isclose` and its cousin [`allclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) have their uses. I usually use them to see if a whole array is very similar to another whole array, which doesn't seem to be your question.

Comment: thanks @senderle, how about comparing against a floating point number like -100.0 i.e. only a 0 after the decimal point

Answer (score 7):

```
arr = np.random.random((3,3))
# find the number of elements that get really close to 1.0
condition = arr == 0.83723156
# count the elements
np.count_nonzero(condition)
```

The value of `condition` is a list of booleans representing whether each element of the array satisfied the condition.  `np.count_nonzero` counts how many nonzero elements are in the array.  In the case of booleans it counts the number of elements with a `True` value.

To be able to deal with floating point accuracy, you could do something like this instead:

```
condition = np.fabs(arr - 0.83723156) < 0.001
```

Answer (score 3):

For floating point arrays [`np.isclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) is much better option than either comparing with the exactly same element or defining a custom range.

```
>>> a = np.array([[ 0.68878371,  0.2511641 ,  0.05677177],
                  [ 0.97784099,  0.96051717,  0.83723156],
                  [ 0.49460617,  0.24623311,  0.86396798]])

>>> np.isclose(a, 0.83723156).sum()
1
```

Note that real numbers are not represented **exactly** in a computer, that is why `np.isclose` will work while `==` doesn't:

```
>>> (0.1 + 0.2) == 0.3
False
```

Instead:

```
>>> np.isclose(0.1 + 0.2, 0.3)
True
```

Comment: I don't think it's a "much better option" than defining a range. The default tolerance values (`rtol` and `atol`) provided by `isclose` are arbitrary, and the results it generates are not always obvious or easy to predict -- to deal with complex floating point arithmetic, it does [even more](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/numeric.py#L24540) floating point arithmetic. A simple range is much easier to reason about precisely. Still, I agree that `isclose` is a useful alternative sometimes, so I linked to your answer from mine.

Answer (score 0):

If it may be of use to anyone: for very large 2D arrays, if you want to count how many time all elements appear within the entire array, one could flatten the array into a list and then count how many times each element appeared:

```
from itertools import chain
import collections
from collections import Counter

#large array is called arr
flatten_arr = list(chain.from_iterable(arr))
dico_nodeid_appearence = Counter(flatten_arr)
#how may times x appeared in the arr
dico_nodeid_appearence[x]
```